# Easiest way to import modified file into git repository

Tags: git

I'm collaborating on a (latex) document using a git repo, however one of our collaborators prefers not to use git. The easiest solution, it seems, is to send him the latest version when he wants to make edits, and then have one of the git users add these changes back into the repo (using 'diff' to patch changes for example).  My question is how one can do this most easily using only git commands i.e. is it possible to override the current files in the repo with his versions and then run a git command to merge these changes with the latest commit? Or should a separate branch first be created?

Comment: best option would be convince this user to use Git :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaboration

Comment: this is a senior (in both senses) member of the collaboration:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you will be dealing with file changes that are not recorded with git, using branches will be easier for you to track changes. Otherwise, your current state can get messed up due to the changes introduced by the other person

Let us say the file you are dealing with is `hello.tex`.

Create a branch, say `no-git-person`, which will be the branch from which you will be sharing the file with the person.

```
git checkout -b no-git-person
```

At this stage, the file is in sync with your master.

Mail/share file from this branch, and once he makes the edits and sends to one of the git using person, **checkout to** `no-git-person` branch and make the commit, maybe signing the commit with your name so that other git users can know

```
git commit -m "[signed by] some meta information here"
```

Merge the master to this branch

```
git merge master
```

**Successful Merge**: In case of successful merge, merge back the file to master

```
git checkout master
git merge no-git-person
```

**Merge Conflict:** In case of a merge conflict, abort the merge

```
git merge --abort
```

Sit together and resolve the changes. Commit and merge with master again.

```
git commit -m "[signature info] resolved conflict"
git checkout master
git merge no-git-person
```

If you want to share again, just do

```
git checkout no-git-person
git merge master // now synced with your latest work; you can share the file from this branch
```

The idea is to keep the changes from the person not using git without polluting the branch in which the git users are working. Incorporate the changes into your work only if you are sure if there are no conflicts.

The problem is the person not using `git` had to wait for git users to give the updated file to make his changes. It defeats the purpose of collaboration.

**If you can, convince that person to use `git`.** It will save you from future collaboration headaches.